# Validating data within a queryset

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a case where I need to merge records into one. Pretty much frontend would provide a bunch of ids, Django will pull the records, validate the data, and create a new db record. In theory, most of the fields should contain the same value, but one field (we are copying the value from all records to the new record). Before creating the new record, I would like to add a validator to make sure the values are equal. What would be the best way to run the comparisons? My thought process is as follow:

1. Get all the records for the given ids.
2. Use the first record as the source of truth ( everything else will get compared against this record ).
3. Compare the values (Here is where I am getting stuck).
4. Create new record.

Also, if you guys have idea on how to avoid hitting the db every time I need to compare a value would be great, this particular model has many fields and I feel hitting the db for every comparison isn't very efficient.

I have added a dummy model to give a better idea of what I am trying to accomplish:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    author = models.CharField()
    year_published = models.DateField()
    field_to_be_merged = ArrayField(
        ArrayField(
            models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True),
            size=8,
        ),
        size=8,
    )
```

`name`, `author`, `year_published` should be the same (I need to make sure they are the same). `field_to_be_merged` contains different values and the new record will display all merged values.

Answer (score 0):

1. we are copying the value from all records to the new record" can you explain more? why would you add all previous records to new one? what will new record contain exactly? can you give an example-end-result, so we can understand better what you want?
2. why not listing existing "name" "author" and "year_published" to user with HTML select-options? If there are 100 "Sol" as name on table, user would see one Sol. This way he/she can see the previous entries and only enters a new name.
3. Even tho I have so many questions about your question, I think what youre describing can be achieved within models class with the help of django's queryset. You can write a django queryset filter and get all the rows that matches your selection and then do your thing.

For example:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    author = models.CharField()
    year_published = models.DateField()
    field_to_be_merged = ArrayField(
        ArrayField(
            models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True),size=8,),
        size=8,)


     def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        db_query_set = TableName.objects.filter("name"="Sol").values_list("author", "year_published")
        # db_query_set will contain "author" and "year_published" values where "name" column matches value of "Sol".
        # Now you can manipulate the queryset data as you want and create final values that you want to save.
        # For example, at the end, it could look like this:
        self.name = new_name
        self.author = new_author
        self.year_published = new_year_published
        self.field_to_be_merged =  new_field_to_be_merged

        super(Book, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

save() function will run whenever Book model is called by form and will do the manipulation for each entry.